# When I try to compile my React app I get a blank screen

Tags: javascript, create-react-app

When I go to compile my Create React App I get a blank screen with a bunch of errors in the console:

[image]

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
const [todos, setTodos] = useState(["take the dogs out for a walk", 
"take the trash out"]);
const [input, setInput] = useState("");

return (
<div className='app'>
<h1>Welcome to my TODO List</h1>  
<input value={input} type="text" />
<input type="text">
<button>Add todo</button>

<h2>List of todos</h2>
{todos.map(todo =>(
<p>{todo}</p>
))}

</input>

</div>
);
}

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';


const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
<React.StrictMode>
<App />
</React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: Please have a look at this section in help: [/help/asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: Give a [mre], **as text**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input tag can't have children, these are the two errors at the bottom.

Inputs are self closing tags

```
<input/>
```

where as a div can have children tags

```
<div>
<input/>
</div>
```

this is your error

```
<input type="text">
<button>Add todo</button>
<h2>List of todos</h2>
{todos.map(todo =>(
<p>{todo}</p>
))}
</input>
```

change this to

```
<div>
<button>Add todo</button>
<input type="text" onChange={()=>{}} value={'make another use state'}/>
<h2>List of todos</h2>
{todos.map(todo =>(
<p>{todo}</p>
))}
</div>
```